# React: Using Child checkbox to update Parent component's state

Tags: reactjs

I have the following Parent component:

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    state = {
      value: 0
    }  
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <Child />
  )
}
```

And the following Child component:

```
export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    state = {
      num: 0
    }  
  }
}

toggleCheckboxChange = () => {
   this.setState({ num: 5})
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>
      {this.state.num}
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.toggleCheckboxChange}
       />
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I want to use the checkbox to set the Child state `num` to 5, and then pass that to the Parent's state `value`.

What would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: It's generally easiest to put the state directly in the parent and then pass the event handlers down through props.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just can't seem to understand how that works, new to React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment, it's easiest if you move the state into the parent.

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ca93x5)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Parent extends Component {

    state = {
        value: 0
    }

    toggleCheckboxChange = ev => {
        this.setState({value: 5})
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Child num={this.state.value} toggleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckboxChange}/>
        );
    }
}

function Child({num, toggleCheckboxChange}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                {num}
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={toggleCheckboxChange}
                />
            </label>
        </div>
    )
}

render(<Parent/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And what if instead of 5 I want to set the Id props of the Child? Will that be {value: this.props.id} in the Parent component?

Comment: @Ruham I'm not sure what you're asking. You can pass any prop through to the child: `<Child id={anythingYouWant} />`

Comment: it should toggle right? Howcome its stuck with 5 after deselecting the checkbox ?

Comment: @Gel Well no, look at the implementation of `toggleCheckboxChange`. If you want it to toggle, have a look at `ev.target.checked` and do as you please. e.g. `this.setState({value: ev.target.checked ? 5 : 0})`

Comment: @mpen yes exactly what I did.  I used ev.target.checked to toggle